# Existential Elimination in Fitch (Barber of Seville)

Tags: logic

To be clear, I'm just struggling to understand why Fitch won't let me use EE. From other examples I've seen, I've set it up correctly for EE. I've also tried using BotE and EE on the desired sentence, various variants of the proof, but it always comes down to Fitch not allowing me to do EE. What am I doing wrong? I'm a noob at Fitch, I can prove this so many ways but Fitch frustrates me to no end.[image]

Comment: Never mind. I didn't cite line 2

Comment: You already posted [the exact same question on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435556/existential-elimination-in-fitch-barber-of-seville). Please don't ask the same question on multiple sites of the network.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy, and thanks for contributing with a question/response! If you haven't done so, please take a quick moment to take the tour. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour More specifics can be found in the help center. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Already asked and answered in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435556/existential-elimination-in-fitch-barber-of-seville). What is the benefit of reposting exactly the same question ?

Answer (score 0):

'EE 2, 3-13'

Existential elimination requires an *existential to eliminate*, and a *subproof* where a witness is assumed that derives a statement that does not include the assumed term.

3-13 is that subproof, but you missed referencing line 2, the existence you wanted to eliminate.